# tkinter - Filter optionmenu options based on previous optionmenu choice

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am building a program where I need to filter out all 'course modules' that are not from the chosen skill level (chosen from a options menu above) from an options menu. My idea is to create ModuD dictionary with only the B skill options (if the user chooses Foundation skill level) and then feed that to the ModuleDDL OptionsMenu where it will display the name (i.e. 'Geology' or 'Reservoir Engineering') but it will return the code (.i.e. B11 or B12).

So I have something like:

```
class Module:

    def __init__(self, code, name, skill, description):
        self.code = code
        self.name = name
        self.skill = skill
        self.description = description

class Askill(Module):
    A11 = Askill(11, 'Fundamentals', 'A', 'description A11')

class Bskill(Module):
    B11 = Bskill(11,'Geology', 'B', 'description B11')
    B12 = Bskill(12,'Reservoir Engineering', 'B', 'description B12')

SkillD = dict(Awareness = 'A', \
              Foundation = 'B', \
              Skill = 'C', \
              Advance = 'D')
selectedSkill = StringVar()

#############  Create Dropdown list for Skill Level ###########
LabelSkillDDL = Label(root, text="Skill Level").pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
SkillDDL = OptionMenu(root, selectedSkill, *SkillD.keys(), command=update_text_box)
SkillDDL.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W, padx=10)
SkillDDL.configure(font=(fonttype, fontsize))


###########  Create Dropdown list for Module ###########
LabelModuleDDL = Label(root, text="Module").pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
ModuleDDL = OptionMenu(root, selectedCode, *ModuD.keys(), command=update_text_box)
ModuleDDL.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W, padx=10)
ModuleDDL.configure(font=(fonttype, fontsize))
```

Any ideas how this could work? Is there a better way I can't see atm?

Many thanks!

Comment: The classes can't create instances of themselves like that.

Comment: Please post what is going wrong, and what the outcome should be.

Comment: Is there a way of creating a dictionary style object with more than one attribute? As far as I understand dicts can only have a key and an attribute.. This would resolve my issue i think. Otherwise is there other way to create a class of a class then? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "V:\GSC_SLB_Test\Personal\Python\GUI Summary Tools CLASS.py", line 114, in <module>
    class Askill(PetrelModule):
  File "V:\GSC_SLB_Test\Personal\Python\GUI Summary Tools CLASS.py", line 116, in Askill
    A11 = Askill(11, 'Fundamentals', 'A', '',\
NameError: name 'Askill' is not defined

Comment: Please add it to your answer, formatted as code. (Select, then CTRL+K)

Comment: Sorry Artemis, it doesn't seem to work. pressing CTRL+K prompts me to type in the browser address bar instead.. :/

Comment: Try selecting it, then press the `{ }` button at the top of the text entry box.

Comment: there is no such thing :(

Comment: Look here to see what I mean: [`{}`](https://i.imgur.com/P5i2D07.jpg)